# How to force exist to retrieve an HTML file "as is", not adding <?xml and not merging </-s?

Tags: html, exist-db

Does anybody know how to force exist to retrieve an HTML file "as is", not adding `<?xml` and not merging `</`-s?

Even wikipedia [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) says:

- Include an extra space in empty-element tags: for example `<br />` instead of `<br/>`.
- Include explicit close tags for elements that permit content but are left empty (for example, `<div></div>`, not `<div />`).

Case:

HTML file stored in eXist DB:

```
<div id="idADADScreen">
  <div id="idADADTop"></div>
  <div id="idADADMiddle">
    <div id="idADADLeft"></div>
    <div id="idADADCenter"></div>
    <div id="idADADRight"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="idADADBottom"></div>
</div>
```

When retrieved with wget, the empty tags are melt:

```
<?xml... ?>

<div id="idADADScreen">
    <div id="idADADTop"/>
    <div id="idADADMiddle">
       <div id="idADADLeft"/>
        <div id="idADADCenter"/>
        <div id="idADADRight"/>
     </div>
     <div id="idADADBottom"/>
</div>
```

In a Chrome and all others, the object hierarchy laughs on />

```
<div id="idADADScreen">
    <div id="idADADTop">
        <div id="idADADMiddle">
            <div id="idADADLeft">
                <div id="idADADCenter">
                    <div id="idADADRight"></div>
                    <div id="idADADBottom"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Right and bottom closed because there are two valid `</div>` s in the original

Comment: I'd be surprised if existdb even stored the original representation of the XML. The HTML Compatibility Guidelines only matter if you want to write XML and have it be parsed by an HTML parser (which was always a crazy idea). If you want to store HTML, then store HTML not XML.

Comment: stored as HTML. No <? xml written into, copied through WebDAV and edited directly from there.

Comment: naturally only a portion was cut and pasted, the document was a healthy xhtml doc without <?xml, yes, exactly not to allow eXist to recognize it as XML... but id did...

Comment: That's my point. It's XML. `<foo/>` and `<foo></foo>` mean the same thing. It doesn't matter which you use so long as you are treating it as XML. It's only when you start trying to treat it as HTML that it matters, which is why the whole XHTML-as-text/html thing is nuts.

Comment: But not in HTML. This is exactly why HTML to be stored "raw".
`<div><div/><div/></div>` is not like `<div><div></div><div></div></div>`; see http://www.arcdev.hu/test/html/selfclosingdiv.html

Comment: But, to quote to the tag wiki: *eXist-db is an open source database management system built using XML technology. **It stores XML data according to the XML data model** and features efficient, index-based XQuery processing.* — if you want to store HTML then don't store it as XML.

Comment: Right. I have used webDav. Never said him it is `<?xml` . Using exist since some 10 years but only for XML storage; now wanted all code in, taking benefit of exist 2 and eXide.

Comment: Thanks, Quentin, anyway.